# move local struct from callee to caller without reallocation in fields

Tags: c++, memory-management, g++, move-semantics

I have the allocator `eallocator`, that manages a memory with execute permission. In **C++11** `std::vector` have `std::vector::data()` member function, that returns pointer to the underlying array of elements. I put some data into array, that treats as an executable code if I call the operator with body:

```
static_assert(std::is_floating_point< F >::value, "F is not floating-point value type");
F result_;
__asm("call *%1"
        : "=&t"(result_)
        :   "r"(code_.data())
        : "memory", "%ax", "%st(1)", "%st(2)", "%st(3)", "%st(4)", "%st(5)", "%st(6)", "%st(7)"
        );
return result_;
```

I get the result of code execution (always single floating-point value).

But when I try to return the structure, say, of type `T`, that contains the `std::vector< std::uint8_t, eallocator< std::uint8_t > > code_` field from some function and place it in `T const` local variable I get undesirable reallocation of `code_`s underlying memory (all offsets in the **rip-relative addressed** code violated).

What should I do to avoid this? How to move local struct variable from calle to local struct variable of caller without reallocation in member fields?

Comment: One way would be to return by (smart) pointer. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yes, it will work. But can we do that by means of some benefits of move-semantics?

Comment: Do you have a move constructor for T?

Comment: Yes, I have `T::T(T&&) nothrow`.

Comment: And `T::T(T const &) = delete; T::T & operator = (T const &) = delete;`

Comment: But when I do `T f() { int y; ... ; return T(y); }` and `T const x(f());` or even `T const x(std::move(f()));` I get the reallocation.

Comment: Does anyone understand my pain?)